# Expr is not parsing the mathematical expression in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I have my bash code like this for example :

```
res=`expr $1+$2`
echo $res
```

or

```
res=$(expr $1+$2)
echo $res
```

then when I execute my code like this `./script01.sh 3 4` I get:

```
3+4
```

Weirdly enough that my code is the exact same as many other tutorials, either there is something wrong with my computer or the problem is stemming from some other thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[~]$ a=1;b=2
[~]$ expr $a+$b
1+2
[~]$ expr $a + $b
3
[~]$ expr $a * $b
expr: syntax error
[~]$ expr $a \* $b
2
```

From the man page:

```
ARG1 + ARG2
              arithmetic sum of ARG1 and ARG2
```

As we can see, you need a space between arguments and operator. In addition you have to escape operators that can be interpreted as globs in bash:

```
Beware that many operators need to be escaped  or  quoted  for  shells.
```

Answer (score 2):

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) has arithmetic operators built-in, so you don't need to call out to expr:

```
res=$(( $1 + $2 ))
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

Your second version should be like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

res=$(expr "$1" + "$2")

echo "$res"
```

And your first version should be:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

res=`expr "$1" + "$2"`

echo "$res"
```

Note the spaces between the `+` operator. And finally using more modern syntax:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

res=$(( $1 + $2 ))

echo "$res"
```

Note the last version is the preferred way.